# I need help with a MKMapView crash

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mkmapview

One of the most frequent crashes of my live app is a crash at MKMapView. It crash at the internal method `-[MKMapView mapTileViewDidFinishLoading:]`. During my test I could not retrace the crash but is very frequent in the crash reports on iTunes Connect. Has anyboday some experience with this crash? It is only a very simple map showing exactly one annotation.

Here is the complete stacktrace of this crash:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000009
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x339737d8 objc_msgSend + 16
1   MapKit                          0x345709ec -[MKMapView mapTileViewDidFinishLoading:]
2   CoreFoundation                  0x344492e4 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:]
3   Foundation                      0x3326981e __NSThreadPerformPerform
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34460f1e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
5   CoreFoundation                  0x34432ba0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
6   CoreFoundation                  0x34432444 __CFRunLoopRun
7   CoreFoundation                  0x34432270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
8   CoreFoundation                  0x34432178 CFRunLoopRunInMode
9   GraphicsServices                0x3026b5ec GSEventRunModal
10  GraphicsServices                0x3026b698 GSEventRun
11  UIKit                           0x31ad011c -[UIApplication _run]
12  UIKit                           0x31ace128 UIApplicationMain
13  MYApp                           0x00002e08 main + 36
14  MYApp                           0x00002dd8 start + 32
```

Comment: Might be worth sharing some...

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue.  Is this happening when your releasing the mapview?  Are you using any overlays or annotations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I may have fixed this issue in my own application.  It appears that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188098/why-am-i-crashing-after-mkmapview-is-freed-if-im-no-longer-using-it) has the correct solution and explanation.

The message that was causing the failure in my application was 'mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap' which is a message of the MKMapViewDelegate.  Try to set the mapView delegate to 'nil' before in your views dealloc method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your are right. I didn't set the delegate to nil before release the map. I will try this and inform you about any news.

Comment: OK now 1 month after implementing the solutions and no new bug reports an can say this works.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this it will solve the problem 100%

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.mapView.delegate = nil;
    mapView=Nil;
    NSLog(@"viewWillDisappear");

}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `[super viewWillDisappear:animated]`

Answer (score 0):

I also had to set the delegate to nil in viewDidDisappear to fix the issue.