# MKMapView still sending messages to delegate after it's superview has been de-alloc'ed

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

EDIT: changed the title. I didn't know it at the time but this is a duplicate of [Why am I crashing after MKMapView is freed if I'm no longer using it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188098/why-am-i-crashing-after-mkmapview-is-freed-if-im-no-longer-using-it)

---

This question is similar to [Why is object not dealloc'ed when using ARC + NSZombieEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408071/why-is-object-not-dealloced-when-using-arc-nszombieenabled) but different enough that I thought it worth throwing out there in case anyone understands and can explain to me what is happening. The other question may be an XCode bug so I presume this could be similar.

Scenario:

1. `RootViewController` has a `tableView` displaying a bunch of items
2. Selecting a cell presents a modal `detailViewController` containing another `tableView`
3. One of the table cells in `detailViewController` contains an `MKMapView` showing the location of the item
4. `mapView.delegate = detailViewController`
5. Dismiss the modal `detailViewController`

Soon after this, the app crashes b/c the `MKMapView` sends `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` to the now dealloc'ed `detailViewController`. This crash repro'ed on a users device with an ad-hoc distribution build so the issue has nothing to do with `NSZombieEnabled`.

I was able to resolve the crash by adding:

```
_mapView.delegate = nil;
```

to the `dealloc` method of the `tableViewCell` containing the mapView.

QUESTION: why is it necessary to nil the delegate when the cell is dealloc'ed? It seems like the `mapView` should be dealloc'ed by ARC when the cell is dealloc'ed leaving this unnecessary. It is good practice to nil delegates but I didn't think it would be required in this case.

EDIT: all subviews of both `detailViewController` and the `UITableViewCells` are declared as `(nonatomic, strong)` properties ala:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)   MKMapView *         mapView;
```

EDIT 2: Guess I need to get better at reading the docs. @fluchtpunkt is correct. Here's the relevant info from the `MKMapView` documentation:

> Before releasing an MKMapView object for which you have set a
>   delegate, remember to set that object’s delegate property to nil. One
>   place you can do this is in the dealloc method where you dispose of
>   the map view.

Comment: Can you post the @strong/@weak property declarations for your `detailViewController`, especially the `MKMapView`?

Comment: done. I have no @weak properties as the app targets iOS 4.3+. The mapView is in a custom `UITableViewCell` as a strong property.

Comment: Sounds like the same thing as pre-ARC, as I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188098/why-am-i-crashing-after-mkmapview-is-freed-if-im-no-longer-using-it

Comment: yep, it is. nothing really to do with ARC at all, just a requirement of MKMapView that I was unaware of. Wish I had seen your question before posting. Nothing like (mis)reading the docs to humble you every now and then.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

MKMapView is not compiled with ARC and because of that the property for `delegate` is still declared as `assign` instead of `weak`.
From the [MKMapView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/delegate):

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<MKMapViewDelegate> delegate
```

---

And from the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html):

> You may implement a dealloc method if you need to manage resources other than releasing instance variables. You do not have to (indeed you cannot) release instance variables, but **you may need to invoke [systemClassInstance setDelegate:nil] on system classes** and other code that isn’t compiled using ARC.

---

For delegates of system classes (NS*, UI*) you have to use the "old" rule of setting delegates to nil when you deallocate the delegate object.

so add a dealloc method to your detailViewController

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.mapView.delegate = nil;
}
```

Comment: well, this is (sort of) what I did. The mapView is in a table cell so when the cell is dealloc'ed I'm now setting `_mapView.delegate = nil`. But still seems a little suspect b/c I have no control over when the `tableCell` is dealloc'ed vs when it's delegate (`detailViewController`) is dealloc'ed. It seems like the `mapView` should be dealloc'ed when it's cell is dealloc'ed already so setting it's delegate to nil then should be redundant, no?

Comment: If you don't use the object anymore ARC has released it for you. However, it is possible that a system class has retained it too. This can always happen and since you don't have control about that you have to nil the delegates of non-ARC classes. If the mapView is part of the cell you should of course set the delegate to nil in the dealloc of the cell.

Comment: I understand and it makes sense when the object being dealloc'ed can explicitly ensure that nothing is holding an unsafe_unretained reference to it. In this example that's not the case as there is no guarantee that the cell wouldn't be retained by another object keeping the `mapView` retained even though the `mapView`'s delegate (`detailViewController`) has been dealloc'ed. Imagine an example where the cell is replaced by a different class. In any case, this seems to be working for this case so I'll likely accept your answer but I'm not convinced that this will resolve all cases. Thanks.

Comment: as a related question, are you advocating this for all assigned delegate properties of non-ARC system classes? For example, how about a `tableView` itself? When the controller owning the `tableView` is dealloc'ed should I explicitly set `tableView.dataSource = nil` and `tableView.delegate = nil`? This is definitely something that wasn't necessary pre-ARC.

Comment: and lastly, your answer is in fact confirmed by the `mapView` docs. I'll add something at the bottom of the question. Guess I should have started there. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that the delegates for such classes should be explicitly set to `nil`, doing it in `dealloc` is already too late. You already lost your reference to the mapview during `viewDidUnload`. You should do the `self.mapView.delegate = nil` BEFORE `viewDidUnload` (so probably `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`)

From my experience, only `MKMapView` and `UIWebView` behave this way.

Comment: that's not correct. viewDidUnload is not always called. You need to nil the delegate in both places.

Comment: also, in this case it's impossible. the mapView is in a UITableCell not a view controller.

Comment: My wording was wrong but I was talking about `viewDidUnload` as a view controller cycle stage. Even if `viewDidUnload` is not called the `IBOutlets` and other weak `UIView` references will zero out after the view hierarchy is unloaded. (Unless you're keeping a strong reference to your views, which you probably shouldn't be doing in the first place)

Comment: I'll clarify. I appreciate your addition to the answer. WRT `viewDidUnload`, you do need set  `mapView.delegate = nil` there as well. The incorrect part is to say `dealloc` is too late. You can't rely solely on `viewDidUnload` as it is not always called.

Comment: As long as your `self.mapView` is still valid by then. Also, I missed your comment to fluchtpunkt that said `The mapView is in a custom UITableViewCell as a strong property. ` so I mentioned about the `view***` methods.